# Setting path with autocommand within a directory tree in Vim

Tags: vim

Let's say I have project residing in `/home/myname/project`. There are couple of subfolders in it too. Can I make a autocommand, so that it sets the path to `/home/myname/project/**` whenever I open a file from any subdirectory of the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the command below.

```
:autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead /home/myname/project/* sil! cd %:h
```

Use the `:lcd` command instead of `:cd` to change the current directory only
for the current window.

Comment: Can you tell me what does sil! part do?

Comment: @yasar11732:  The `:silent` command with `!` modifier executes the command following it suppressing all messages (including error messages).  In this case it is necessary to hide the error message about an empty path which would be otherwise shown when one opens a new file without path (e.g. `:e`, not `:e /some/where`).